# stash and restore highlight colors with lua and neovim

Tags: neovim, highlight, lua

I would like to toggle an option and with it the highlight color of Whitespace.

Before setting the color with `vim.api.nvim_command("hi Whitespace guifg=#ff0000")` I would like to stash the current value for the highlight away so that I can reapply it later.

```
if inactive then
    ...
    hi_whitespace = <somehow get the current value of the highlight>
    vim.api.nvim_command("hi Whitespace guifg=#ff0000")
    ...
else
    ...
    vim.api.nvim_command("hi Whitespcae"..hi_whitespace)
    ...
end
```